# How to print lines if two fields have identical values?

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I am new in unix, I have a question regarding data subsetting, I would appreciate anyone's help.
I have 23G input file containing millions of rows, but I want to keep only those rows where the first and 4th column are identical (scaffold names). here is the first few rows of my data set:

```
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA 1
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097  1029 NA 1
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097  1044 NA -0.0463767871013283
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097  1045 NA -0.939576278422824
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097  1130 NA -0.0831304705346077
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097  1180 NA -0.931681175211672
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097  1187 NA -0.940010336852543
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097  1202 NA 1
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097  1224 NA 1
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097  1269 NA 1
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097  1313 NA -0.201478578143067
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_798049_802097  1384 NA 1
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_878564_884314  3259 NA -0.595441932439136
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_878564_884314  3304 NA 0.745699172241005
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_878564_884314  3319 NA -0.570318634275133
tscaffold94_798049_802097   999 NA tscaffold94_878564_884314  3588 NA -0.60363963711489
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is your friend in this case; the columns become variables in the `awk` script, and so it's easy to check for equivalence (or not), and perform an action like print (the current row is implied)

```
awk '{if($1 == $4) print}' < input
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: or simply `awk '$1==$4' <infile`

Comment: If you're going to do further processing, and you are learning bioinformatics, I would recommend investigating R.